# Who are these two students in the back of Itoshiki's class?

Tags: sayonara-zetsubou-sensei

In Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei s01e01 @17:37 there are these two peculiar students in the back right with a different art style and dark blue hair which stands out from everybody else:

[image]

Are they anyone special from another work by one of the staff, or is it a cameo from an unrelated title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are extras that were used in the Pani Poni Dash series, the series that Shaft worked on before the Zetsubou Sensei series. The director Shinbou is known for throwing in references and parodies of previous works.

[image: Here's a screenshot featuring them.]